# How to add collection view after added from entry in medicine page to anther collection view in main page and How to show DisplayAlert in view model?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

**i have *main page* and *medicine page*, inside view model have command to add entry to collection view(addMedicinechoice) in medicine page.**

I need after Pop medicine page to main page copy addMedicinechoice to another list in main page?

```
   namespace HOSPITALEMERGNCY.Models
{
    public class ForMessege:Page
    {
    }
}

namespace HOSPITALEMERGNCY.Models
{
    public class ListMedicine
    {
        public int MedicineId { get; set; }
       public string MedicineName { get; set; }
        public string AddMedicine { get; set; }
        public string AddUnit { get; set; }
        public string AddDosage { get; set; }
        public string AddQuantity { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace HOSPITALEMERGNCY.ViewModels
{
    public class ListMedicineViewModel
    {
        private readonly INavigation _navigation;
        public ObservableCollection<ListMedicine> ListAll { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ListMedicine> addMedicinechoice { get; set; }
        public string Medicine { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string Dosage { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddChoice => new Command(AddMed);
        
        public async void AddMed()
        {
            var messege = new ForMessege();
          
           
                if (Medicine != null && Unit != null && Dosage != null && Quantity != null)
                {
                    addMedicinechoice.Add(new ListMedicine { AddMedicine = Medicine, AddUnit = Unit, AddDosage = Dosage, AddQuantity = Quantity });
                    
                }
                else
                if (Medicine != null || Unit != null || Dosage != null || Quantity != null)
                {
                    await messege.DisplayAlert("تنبيه", "ادخل جمبع الحقول", "نعم");
                }
            
        }
        public ListMedicineViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            _navigation = navigation;

            addMedicinechoice = new ObservableCollection<ListMedicine>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this has been discussed dozens of times.  You can pass a reference to your Collection to the Add page.  You can use MessagingCenter to pass a message from the add page to the list page.  You can use an event or completion handler.

Comment: For MessageCenter, you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center. Or you can upload a small instance and attach the link here

Comment: thank you i used MessagingCenter and  worked thank you again